# Error propagation on weighted mean

Tags: statistics, error-propagation

I understand that, if errors are random and independent, the addition (or difference) of two measured quantities, say $x$ and $y$, is equal to the quadratic sum of the two errors. In other words, the error of $x + y$ is given by $\sqrt{e_1^2 + e_2^2}$, where $e_1$ and $e_2$ and the errors of $x$ and $y$, respectively.

However, I have not yet been able to find how to calculate the error of both the **arithmetic mean** and the **weighted mean** of the two measured quantities. How do errors propagate in these cases?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first assertion deals wtih *mean squared errors*, which in probabilistic terms translates into *standard deviations*.

Now, probability says that the variance of the sum of two independent variables is the sum of the variances. That is, if $z = x + y$ ($x$ and $y$ indep), then $\sigma_z^2 =  \sigma_x^2  + \sigma_y^2 $ and  $$e_z = \sigma_z =  \sqrt{\sigma_x^2  + \sigma_y^2} = \sqrt{e_x^2  + e_y^2}  $$

Knowing this, and knowing that $Var(a X) = a^2 Var(X)$, if $z = a x + (1-a) y$ (weighted mean, if $ 0\le a \le1$) we get:

$$\sigma_z^2 =  a^2\sigma_x^2  + (1-a)^2\sigma_y^2 $$

$$e_z =  \sqrt{a^2 e_x^2  + (1-a)^2 e_y^2} = a \sqrt{ e_x^2  + \left(\frac{1-a}{a}\right)^2 e_y^2}  $$

In particular, if $a=1/2$ , then $e_z =  \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{ e_x^2  + e_y^2} $

Another particular case: if $e_x = e_y$ then

$$e_z =  e_x \sqrt{a^2 +(1-a)^2}$$

Comment: If I understand it correctly, and in a more general form, if we had $n$ independent variables with their corresponding weights, $c_{1}, c_{2}...c_{n}$, the error of their weighted mean (when $\sum_{i=1}^n{c_{i}} = 1$) would be $\sqrt{c_{1}^2 e_1^2  + c_{2}^2 e_2^2 + ... + c_{n}^2 e_n^2}$. Right?

Comment: @plok that's right

Answer (score 2):

The arithmetic mean is just a scaled version of the sum, so you just need to know that the error scales as the quantity itself under scaling; thus the error in the arithmetic mean is $\sqrt{e_1^2+e_2^2}/2$. (You need to enclose the argument of the root in curly braces instead of parentheses to have it displayed under the square root.)

For more general [error propagation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ErrorPropagation.html), you need to multiply the errors with the partial derivatives with respect to the individual quantities. In the case of the geometric mean, $g(x,y)=\sqrt{xy}$, these are

$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}=\frac12\sqrt{\frac yx}\;,\quad\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}=\frac12\sqrt{\frac xy}\;,$$

so the error $e$ is

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
e
&=&
\sqrt{\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}e_x\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}e_y\right)^2}\\
&=&
\frac12\sqrt{\frac yxe_x^2+\frac xye_y^2}
\\
&=&
\frac1{2g}\sqrt{(e_xy)^2+(e_yx)^2}\;.
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Comment: could you maybe provide a general equation for the geometric mean of n observations g(x1,x2,...xn)?

Comment: @Roey: The geometric mean is $\sqrt[n]{x_1\cdots x_n}$, so the derivatives are

$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_i}=\frac1n\frac g{x_i}\;,$$ so the error is 

$$\sqrt{\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_i}e_1\right)^2+\dotso+\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}_ie_n\right)^2}=\frac gn\sqrt{\left(\frac{e_1}{x_1}\right)^2+\dotso+\left(\frac{e_n}{x_n}\right)^2}\;.$$

Comment: Thanks! I assume you meant though:          $(\frac{\partial g}{\partial xn}e_n\right)^2$ in the left hand side of the equation.

Comment: @Roey: I did, thanks, and likewise with index $1$ in the first term. (Your comment isn't rendering properly because you left off the `\left` at the beginning.)